# how to know no. of nodes running in a map job

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

does the number of input splits determine the number of running nodes in a mapreduce job.

i mean if i have 5 input splits will this make them distributed on 5 nodes to be processed. And is the number of map tasks is similar to number of nodes ?

How to check that in clouderavm

Comment: Did you mean to ask how many nodes are used in a mapreduce job?

Comment: yes ... and how to give one input split to each of them

Comment: I think all tasks are attempted to be run on the datanodes that contain the data that you want. It's usually a bad idea to use 1 task per node and I'm not sure you can control that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No splits do not determine number of nodes.

Hadoop Cluster i.e NameNode ,DataNodes and other service are setup by Hadoop Admin based on size of data.

On Cloudera VM open browser(Mozilla for CDH3) there is a bookmark Namenode status.
Click on that and Namenode contains all the metadata about the cluster you are working on.

To know about job information executed by Map Reduce framework, Job Tracker is there.

Comment: thanks for the reply. when i run the mapper of the job it forms 5 input splits and in the cloudera manager it formed 5 maptasks.. My question now is how the mapper  distribute these tasks or all of them run on single node.. If you have a tutorial link it will be great .. Thank you...

Comment: Which Cloudera VM version u are using?

Comment: clouderaquickstart vm